# What can schema template achieve to the performance of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I wonder if any of you guys studied schema template of Apache IoTDB? If I include data types when writing data into IoTDB, I think there is no need to create a schema template. Also, I actually tested and found that there is no need to create a schema template in advance when writing. I originally thought that the schema template was something similar to a table structure, so now I am a little confused on what schema template can do, and how it should be used in IoTDB. Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `schema template` in Apache IoTDB is somewhat similar to the table structure in a relational database. `Schema template` can effectively reduce the memory usage of metadata. If the data measurement points of all devices stored in IoTDB are the same, you can use `schema template` to avoid duplication of creating multiple time series for each device, but to share the same template.